# Windows neither showing up in BIOS nor Grub

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

As in the title, i cannot boot into windows because it does not show up as an boot entry.
I just wiped all my linux partitions to reinstall and reorder them. I did not touch the windows drive.

My suspicion is that the win bootloader for whatever reason got installed onto my fedora drive, which i just wiped.

##### My old layout:

```
# Windows
/dev/sda
600M EFI
6M Unknown
600M EFI # Why twice? idk
240G Windows Data

-----------------
# Fedora
/dev/sdb
500M EFI
628M Unknown
1M Bios Boot
120G /

----------------
# Other
/dev/sdd
128M EFI
1M Bios Boot
300G / # Arch

128M EFI
1M Bios Boot
600G / # Gentoo

NOTE: All values are estimated from what i remember seeing in the windows drive manager
(not sure what its correct name is) and lsblk.
```

##### What i've done:

I wiped Fedora, Arch and Gentoo (or rather the drives) with `cfdisk /dev/sdb # and /dev/sdd`, deleted all partitions and then did `wipefs -f /dev/sdb # and /dev/sdd`.

I cant mount the windows partition and access the data.

Can i restore the bootloader, maybe with a recovery stick of windows?

Comment: Yes, a Windows recovery disk can do Startup Repair. See [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is valid: installing Linux installed a "hook", i.e., grub, in the booting process, so that grub(2) points to either Linux or Windows. Though you could manually modify filenames to change the boot order, it's easier to use a tool to fix it. Before trying this, make a disk image lest repairs cause data loss.

- Use Windows own [*BCDEdit*, run from a Windows RE (Recovery Environment) disk or USB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/use-winre-to-troubleshoot-startup-issue), (previously, *Win PE*). You can [create the WinRE media from Windows 10](https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/windows-10-repair-boot-usb-0310.html), or use a third-party ISO, such as [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) or an [alternative](https://www.geckoandfly.com/32030/bootable-windows-pe-recovery-repair/).
- A number of disk imaging tools, such as free [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), can make repair media which includes an automatic boot repair process.
- If all else fails, [download the appropriate Windows ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), and put it on USB with their *Media Creation Tool*. Boot from that media to reinstall/repair Windows, keeping files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the Recovery disk, you may run Startup Repair.

You need to boot into
*Advanced Startup > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Startup Repair*.

For more information and screenshots, see the article
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).